# Build & Deploy 2016 Web Development (switch from Gulp to Webpack possible?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, gulp, webpack

i run the last years a custom designed gulp workflow with lots of nice and helpful features. since i changed few frameworks and some new better tools came out i want to take some time to rewrite my workflow to the latest and greatest standards. the build system is basically running all day on my machine when im developing so a big factor for me is to make it as fast and as possible without using to much performance. i was first looking at the new Gulp 4 system and was thinking to write it this time in es6 or typescript. then i had a look for broccoli which uses trees instead of streams which makes it faster as gulp. but broccoli seams not really active and im not sure if there are many plugins. so i was thinking i use gulp to start broccoli and run most of the stuff in broccoli and thinks no plugins available with gulp. but right at the moment im looking into webpack and it seems to be the new in thing. it also possible to watch and rebuild with it. i'm just starting to get more deep into it but i think lot people had the same progress like me and i would love to here what way you choose and why.

i do all the normal stuff every webdev needs.
sass to css, ecmascript / typescript to es5, linting, compression, optimization from images and so on. i also use it to deliver the stuff to the server with sftp or git, make backups and so on.

here and there i have some custom written stuff where i was using normal javascript or a plugin to run shell code or exec programs.
can i do this kind of stuff with webpack too?

ok, would be awesome to here what you are using and how you think about the hole build & deploy stuff i wrote here ...

cheerio bin2hex